# help navigating terminal

Tags: command-line

I'm new to Ubuntu and know about as much about programming langue as a rock does. so I would like to know if there exist any books with the different commands (kinda like a dictionary style or something) or just an online guide to help out. I have used DOSBox before but it's been awhile since then so I do know how programming works if that helps out

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Shell (terminal) can be used to enter commands which has nothing at all to do with programming, or it can be used to script (simple programming) tasks to automate tasks. Due to your frequent use of the programming word, I'm assuming you want help to script, so I'll offer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Beginners/BashScripting.  I'd suggest though you get familiar with using terminal/shell before you start scripting (see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal possibly first)

Comment: @guiverc I would recommend starting with Introduction to Linux https://www.tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/ first before anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Going by your title, What I interpret is you need **Navigation commands**, shortcuts or tips-tricks related to that.

In that case Read this section under ***Chapter 1: Getting started with GNU/Linux*** from book :

#### [Section 1.1: Useful shortcuts](https://books.goalkicker.com/LinuxBook/)

Please see the About Page that states :

> This Linux® Notes for Professionals book is compiled from Stack Overflow
>   Documentation, the content is written by the beautiful people at Stack Overflow.
>   Text content is released under Creative Commons BY-SA, see credits at the end
>   of this book whom contributed to the various chapters. Images may be copyright
>   of their respective owners unless otherwise specified

Also there is lots of Linux knowledge documented by experienced community guys. Have a look at that also.

Feel free to add-in more details.